# Unable to use hooper API in vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, carousel

I have used [Hooper](https://baianat.github.io/hooper/) to successfully build a carousel in my vue project and I want to trigger the hooper.update() method in order to resize the carousel items properly because sometimes the carousel will apply a 0px width to the carousel elements (which is not intended).

Relevant code:

```
<template>
<hooper ref="carousel" :settings="hooperSettings">
  <slide v-for="(item, index) in cards" :key="index">
    <custom-card :card="item"></listing-card>
  </slide>
  <hooper-navigation slot="hooper-addons"></hooper-navigation>
</hooper>
<v-btn @click="resize()"></v-btn>
</template>

<script>
  import { Hooper, Slide, Navigation as HooperNavigation } from 'hooper';
  components: {ListingCard, Hooper, Slide, HooperNavigation},
  data () {
    let data = {
      hooperSettings: {
        itemsToShow: 1,
        breakpoints: {
          600: {
            itemsToShow: 2
          },
          960: {
            itemsToShow: 3
          },
          1264: {
            itemsToShow: 4,
          }         
        }
      },
   }
   return data;
 },

 methods : {
   resize(){
     this.$refs.carousel.update();
   }
 }
</script>
```

When the resize method is triggered, I get the console error "this.$refs.carousel.update is not a function". I'm not sure what is missing in my code, since the hooper API provides examples where the hooper element is given a ref prop which is referenced in the method that triggers update.

How can I trigger the hooper.update method?

Comment: When is `resize` being fired?

Comment: I didn't include that portion of the code but it's in a separate method. For this example I can add it to a button...

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoint in `resize()` to inspect the `carousel` object? Or maybe `console.log(this.$refs.carousel, this.$refs.carousel.update)`?